# How to execute an executable by android application at runtime

Tags: android, compiler-construction

I want to make an application in which the user sends a code to the server, the server compiles the code, (I was thinking compilation by LLVM) and the executable is created at the server, this executable file can be executed on  android. Then I send the executable back to the android device from server. Then is it possible that I can be able to run this executable by my android app which I designed in my way, to accomplish some purpose ?
How do I achieve it.

Comment: I think it should be possible to run the compiled application on the android, because suppose I compiled application for android then it should work.

Comment: I think this question needs more details. It is kind of vague and I am not sure what you have already tried and what you want to achieve?

What kind of `code` are you sending to the server?

What do you mean by "this executable file can be executed on android" and "I can be able to run this executable by my android app which I designed in my way, to accomplish some purpose"?

Comment: Code, it means my language, in my project, I have implemented a simple language, just simple basic language, its made in python, on android I have the coded text file of the language, this code will be sent to the server, the server having a compiler will compile the code, and will return the compiled output file, I also want that this file will run by the android app.

Comment: Suppose, the code was fibbonacci number, I made a function for it on android device, this device sends the fibbonacci function in the language I designed, then server will return the machine output of the fibbonacci function which can be made to run on android, as the function in machine code is obtained by server, there would be some activity on android which can execute this, it will give 2 integers to the function, and expects an integer as result.

Comment: Why do you want to specifically run the executable on the device? Wouldn't it be easier to run the executable on the server itself and just return the result to the android app?

Comment: Nope, not for this case, because the executable for the code is made, now it will remain in the android device, next time, it would be fast and easy to calculate the fibonacci, if executable code is there, similarly other best way would be, no need for a server, for this, I need to write the compiler in java, now its in python using llvm I don't think it would be easy to do compiling stuff.

Comment: I think what you are asking currently might not be allowed by Android as it would be a major security concern (executing unknown executable files from a server written in an unknown language) - This should not be allowed.

Even if you do manage to compile your code locally using Java, Still the problem of executing the (unknown) executable files would be there.

There is one way I know that Android code can work with executable files, but that is only for Native code (i.e. written in C) using the Android [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/). Try checking it out if it helps you.

Comment: This is too broad for SO for one main reason: in principle this can be done, but there are so many details and moving parts that need to be resolved, that anyone can comment with "what about this or that?" and still not cover the problem space. Just the "send code to server and compile it for Android" is a tall order, never mind delivery.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) which apparently works on Android devices.

Comment: I think that the question is totally fine. It assumes a lot of work, but why should only simple question be asked? Down to the topic, there are guides on the web on how to compile an Android application and install it on a device using command-line tools. You can start here. Do not expect too much documentation: Google is open about their closedness. Probably, you will get stuck because of lack of documentation.